# Get data from API in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, rest, api, token

I want to import some reports into Excel using rest API against Toogl. 
Specs: https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/reports.md

I have one access token to be used. Can I easily the pre-defined "Get data" methods in Excel to import the data? Struggling to find out.

Answer (score 7):

This should be fairly easy to do. You can do a GET request in Excel using `XmlHttpRequest` as per [this quick tutorial](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/). A simple request per the tutorial would be:

```
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
myurl = "http://requestb.in/15oxrjh1" //replace with your URL
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.Send
MsgBox(xmlhttp.responseText)
```

Authentication per the API you linked is done by passing headers in the request which would look something like:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", AuthCredentials
```